# laravel-websockets can't connect with client ( WebSocket connection to wss://***:6001 failed)

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am using `beyondcode/laravel-websockets: 1.9.0` in my Laravel project

when I run

```sh
php artisan websockets:serve
```

[image]

but in browser, client can not connect with server
[image]

I try to fix this by:

1. clean all cache

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan websockets:clean
php artisan websockets:restart
```

2. using a specific version of composer/npm package which I success ran in other project

But none of these helped.

---

The most strange thing is that, when I run `php artisan websockets:serve` in other laravel project dir, everything goes well

[image]

but after I deploy it in an entir new server which doesn't have other laravel project on it, errors still.

---

Why? How can I fix this?

Sorry for my poor English, thanks a lot!

Comment: Check your keys on both sides.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir After updating key in both `.env`，in current dir (chongbai), I still can't establish between server and client, in other project(bootstrap), I can get a wrong key error

Comment: What i s your pusher version ?

Comment: On your new server might be port 6001 is blocked.

Comment: I am using `pusher-js:4.4.0` and `pusher/pusher-php-server: 3.3.1`. I think it's a server error, because I everything go well when I run `websockets:serve` in other dir without front-end changings. I have checked the 6001 port and it's open for all.

Comment: Make sure your `laravel-echo-server.json authHost` matches the one within frontend configuration